# Why isn't a non overridden overloaded function being inherited when I override one of its other overloads?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading

Say that six times fast... Why doesn't this compile in MSVC 2010?

```
class A {
public:
    void foo(int a, int b) { };
    void foo(int a) { };
};
class B: public A {
public:
    void foo(int a, int b) { }; // <-- comment this out to compile
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;
    b.foo(1); // <-- doesn't compile... shouldn't B just inherit this overload?
}
```

Comment: How did you find that so fast?  I searched for awhile.  I didn't use the word resolution though.

Comment: I googled "inherit overloaded function".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was all i needed.  So if its a duplicate, how do I remove it?

Comment: You can delete your own question but not if it has an upvoted answer, or more than 1 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override, you override the *name*, not the specific overload. So it hides all overloads from the base class. To address, you can put `using A::foo;` in your derived class to bring the overloads down into `B`.